# I need to create a Yammer group using API?

Tags: yammer

Is there any undocumented yammer API to create a Group ?

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this but the Ruby docs suggest so (was looking for better API documentation for a colleague and stumbled across it):
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/yammer/yam/Yammer/Api/Group#create_group-instance_method

It POSTs to the endpoint /api/v1/groups with the parameters name (string), description (string), private (boolean) and show_in_directory (boolean).

Hope that might provide some help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to create yammer group using API

```
 function createGroup(name, permalink, isPrivate) {

                yam.platform.request({
                    url: 'groups.json?name=' + encodeURIComponent(name) + '&permalink=' + permalink + '&private=' + isPrivate,
                    method: 'POST',
                    success: function (data) {
                       // deferred.resolve(data);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
            });

        }
```